# str(list[index]): IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm just trying to load a file, extract its first and third columns, randomize them, and generate a new file as follows:

```
import random
import numpy as np

q0 = np.loadtxt("G:\\out.txt")[:, 0].tolist()
q2 = np.loadtxt("G:\\out.txt")[:, 2].tolist()

z0 = [round(random.uniform(-4,4),4) for x in range(488)]
z2 = [round(random.uniform(-4,4),4) for x in range(488)]

r_pos_coord = [round(sum(x),3) for x in zip(q0,z0)]
r_tar_coord = [round(sum(x),3) for x in zip(q2,z2)]

t_pos_coord = [round(random.uniform(0,360),4) for x in range(488)]
t_tar_coord = [round(random.uniform(0,360),4) for x in range(488)]

par1 = [random.randint(0,1) for x in range(488)]
par2 = [x-1 if x==1 else x+1 for x in par1]
p = [1 for x in range(488)]

with open('G:\\target.txt', 'w') as writer:
    for index in range(1,488):
        writer.write(str(r_pos_coord[index]))
        writer.write(' \t')
        writer.write(str(t_pos_coord[index]))
        writer.write(' \t')
        writer.write(str(r_tar_coord[index]))
        writer.write(' \t')
        writer.write(str(t_tar_coord[index]))
        writer.write(' \t')
        writer.write(str(par1[index]))
        writer.write('\t')
        writer.write(str(par2[index]))
        writer.write('\t')
        writer.write(str(p[index]))
        writer.write('\n')
```

AFAIK, both `r_pos_coord` and `r_tar_coord` are lists now. So, I should be able to access their entries by their indices. However, Python throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    writer.write(str(r_pos_coord[index]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: `q0` has `len` less than `488`. When you `zip`, `r_pos_coord` has len less than 488. At some point, there's an index error in your loop

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger and see what the value of `index` was, as well as what was in `r_pos_coord`?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, the list index you passed is out of range, i.e. >= len of the list you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q0` has `len` less than `488`. When you `zip`, `r_pos_coord` has len less than 488. At some point, there's an index error in your loop. You likely want to have a fixed length not to have this unpredictable behavior

Look at an MCVE

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [10,20,30]

list(zip(a,b))
```

yield

```
[(1,10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]
```

Now, suppose you wish to zip based on the longest `len` of both array. [`itertools` has a nice function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html) for that

```
import itertools as it
list(it.zip_longest(a,b))
```

yields

```
[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, None)]
```

For fixed `488`-length lists zipped with variable IO `out.txt` files, `zip_longest` is probably the way to go.